# PHP enquiry is not included in email

Tags: php, html, email, contacts

I'm fairly new to the world of php (3 days experience to be precise). I'm trying to send an email from a "Contact us" page and everything works fine, except the larger message or enquiry, any help would be mighty fine!

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-enquiry">
        <?php echo $entry_enquiry; ?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea name="enquiry" rows="10" id="input-enquiry" class="form-control" style="font:;color:#333333"><?php echo $enquiry; ?></textarea>
        <?php if ($error_enquiry) { ?>
            <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_enquiry; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the code for sending the email

```
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <input class="button btn btn-theme-default" type="submit"
               value="<?php $to='name@email.com';
                            $subject='Message from Contacs us';
                            mail($to, $subject, $enquiry, "From:".$email); 
                            echo $button_submit;
                       ?>" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code retrieving the form variables?

Comment: From a database using a separate php code, I should add that this is not my code, I am editing another persons code

Answer (score 4):

That's not how HTML and PHP work - you're sending a mail every time you render the submit button of that form.

The call to `mail()` actually performs the "send mail" action as soon as it's hit by the interpreter.

What you need to do is have a function which tests the form data, then if-and-only-if the data are valid, sends the mail and redirects you to a thank-you page (or renders it itself).

Comment: So I should add a if($_POST) thingy? And additional if statements checking if the different areas are empty?

Comment: Maybe - I have no idea how your form works because you didn't supply it in your question. There are hundreds of examples of how this process works if you google around, though, and many different ways to do it. What you really would benefit from is separating your PHP code from the HTML. I know it's tempting to throw them all together, but ignore any tutorials which show code like that - it's so 2002.